# Mysqli access denied , using UNIX socket

Tags: mysql, php, socket

I am trying to learn PHP, and I am setting up the database connection.
On Mysql Workbench, I created a database called php, and created a table.
Then I created the account "sam"@"localhost",(I am using Ubuntu desktop, and `sam` is the output of `whoami` ) with auth_socket, Granted ALL on *.* , and when I press `ctrl+alt+T` and input `mysql` and press `enter` , I can successfully login.
Now I followed https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php , and tried using socket, I failed.

```
2021/08/13 16:54:35 [error] 1363#1363: *11 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'sam'@'localhost' in /var/www/php/my2.php on line 3PHP message: PHP Warning:  main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /var/www/php/my2.php on line 5" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /my2.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost:803"
```

And here is my code.
<?php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "sam", Null, "php");

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
```

The output is nothing in a browser.

Then I tried this.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Connecting MySQL Server</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php
         $dbhost = 'localhost';
         $dbuser = 'sam';
         //$dbpass = 'root@123';
         $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser,NULL,NULL,NULL,"/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock");
         
         if($mysqli->connect_errno ) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s<br />", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
         }
         printf('Connected successfully.<br />');
         $mysqli->close();
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

The output is  `Connect failed: Access denied for user 'sam'@'localhost'`
With log

```
2021/08/13 16:59:17 [error] 1363#1363: *13 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'sam'@'localhost' in /var/www/php/mysqli.php on line 10" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /mysqli.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost:803"
```

I don't have password for user `sam` on mysql.

```
MariaDB [mysql]> select user,password from user;
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user      | password                                  |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| root      |                                           |
| someone   | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
| someone   | *9B8A3238012965AC630589D859535EA0B7C231A7 |
| someone   | *AF411B6C73B3AC3A2316A309A71758175CC14FEE |
| someone   | *D76A454D84260E84578F09915624F275F3D0E08B |
| sam       |                                           |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

I changed the actrual username to someone to protect privacy. You can see that `sam` have no password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your Mysql Workbench to set a password for the user `sam` and use that password for connecting with the mysqli library. I don't know if Mysql Workbench does have a click-through option to do so, if not or if you prefer the SQL way, use something like:

```
CREATE USER 'sam'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'choose_a_safe_password'
```

Comment: What if I want to use password-less?
I learnt that more passwords means more risk. Besides, the password will be in plain_text in php.
Is there an option to omit password in my php?

Comment: I don't know about mysql auth without password. Could you explain why you think "more passwords mean more risk"? Where did you learn that? I strongly disagree.

Comment: have a look at https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/11/01/use-mysql-without-a-password/
-> use `IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket;` instead of a password and a linux user with the same name can connect without specifying a password.

Comment: You use ssh instead of a password, and ssh keys are prior to passphrases.

Comment: how you secure your ssh connection is completely independent of how you connect to mysql from a php script running on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. Maybe I should put my brain into the microwave. Haha